# Query text, show all results if no query in url

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2016

`ContentTypeId:0x01010062A988F9081BD142926BC79A5AA59288* {QueryString.Document}`

I'm using this Query text to show all documents of a specific `ContentType` and if a specific Query parameter exist, like this:

```
?Document=Guidelines
```

This works and shows all Documents that has metadata term Guidelines.

But is there some way I can add, so that if there is no `?Document` at all then it will show all documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this works

```
ContentTypeId:0x01010062A988F9081BD142926BC79A5AA59288* ?{QueryString.Document}
```

Or

```
ContentTypeId:0x01010062A988F9081BD142926BC79A5AA59288* {?{QueryString.Document}}
```